# Any Video formats that render with Alpha Channel?

Tags: rendering, transparency, file-format

Does anyone know if there are any **video** formats (besides the HUGE uncompressed avis) that you can render in that maintain the alpha channel? (i.e. for after FX etc.)

I used to use quicktime, but that's no longer an option.  I know you can render in png. or other image formats, but video is significantly smaller, and I often work on machines with less space & resources.

Comment: Could you give a reason a video format is needed? (instead of image files?)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294813/export-a-video-in-transparent-for-use-on-the-web

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using OSX you can use its Quicktime support:

- Selecting any of the video formats in the Output panel.
- In the Encoding panel change the format to Quicktime and select a codec that supports alpha (such as HuffYUV).

[image]

Comment: Does HuffYUV really support alpha? If so, why is there no RGBA choice, as there is for, say, "QT rle/QT animation" or FFmpeg video codec #1" (whatever that is)?

Comment: @WChargin Indeed it does. The UI is misleading and could do a number of changes.

Comment: @Aldrik, if the UI isn't showing RGBA when it should, this could be reported as a bug.

Comment: Any similar options if I don't have OSX?

Comment: Important to note: This chosen solution is valid for the old version of Blender (2.79), it might be different for Version 2.8x

Answer (score 10):

You can consider using two files - flat video and alpha mask video.

That way you can use any modern codec, without being limited to exotic formats that support alpha in video. And you can have separate quality settings for video and alpha with this method.

To achieve transparency in Adobe After Effects you will need to set the alpha video as the other's TrkMat parameter.

Comment: That's creative; I like that.  How do you render that separately in blender? Is it just an alpha pass in the compositor?

Comment: @Wilhelm yes. In the compositor, with "Use Nodes" checked, disconnect the **Image > Image** noodle and replace it with **Alpha > Image**. See [this example](http://i.imgur.com/SyHTSoi.png).

Comment: I experienced some nasty jitter when the camera moves quickly, the Alpha channel acts like jello

Comment: I don't think this will work if your rendering video on as a texture as there is no way to add a mask.  It just needs an alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

There are no compressed video formats supported (directly) by Blender that also support alpha & high compression rates - HuffYUV, QuickTimeRLE support alpha but will still produce large files).

*As noted in another answer, OSX can use QuickTime, so if you're on OSX see @avvi's answer.*

---

Since the questioner mentions file-size.

While not a video format, but JPEG2000 is a compressed image format that supports alpha.

Note that unlike PNG its a *lossy* compression, making it more suitable for storing video, even though its an image format.
Its a standard for [digital cinema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Cinema_Package) for example.

Comment: So is PNG. This question is about video.

Comment: True, but it is one of the few image formats that uses lossy compression and supports alpha. Its also the default for digital cinema - http://www.jpeg.org/apps/cinema.html

Comment: How are you suggesting that it be used to answer the question, though? (Not my downvote, by the way.)

Comment: @WChargin, The user didn't say why they needed a video format specifically, and since there are not many lossy image formats that support alpha (JPEG doesn't for example), I thought it may help some users who want to write very long animations, smaller then PNG's or TAGA's, but also keeping alpha. The one answer which was accepted here is also platform specific (OSX only).

Answer (score 2):

There are versions of ProRes that do support Alpha channels: ProRes4444 and the high bitrate versions of the DNxHD and DNxHR codecs. But you can't encode directly on them from blender. You would need an external encoder or ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

If .mov file is okay for you, here are the setting to get a transparent background (alpha channel) video output form Blender.

[image]

Comment: Using the PNG codec also seems to work with the MPEG-4 container.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this with Blender 2.80 RC1 and you can use quicktime RLE (you don't need Mac OS X, this works on Linux too, so all OS)

Use these settings in video:

[image]

These are the default settings. It seems to work with compression too.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this. Although Huff is a great lossless format, its lossless. From my experiments, the QT rle / QT Animation seems to work perfectly. It seems to not be affected by the compression settings but it uses about 10% the file size of HuffYUV.

Comment: I can confirm both huff and QT rle both work (and on a windoez PC) Huff is uncompressed and huge. the qt rle version is compressed but you dont seem to find any way to change the rates. These, so far have been the only options of worth. Ive tried a few now myself but these have been the only fruitful solution. early days...

Comment: I was looking if someone realized this: QT encoding is fixed in its bitrate. I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I did some Googling on this because I didn't know this was actually supported by *any* format.

From what I've discovered; 32bit video formats support it; but it isn't always supported, so you will need to do some testing with different formats. FLV supports the alpha channel, and theoretically, so should Theora, but it strips out this information.

Your best bet if you need to do FX, would be to use Chroma keying, so you can overlay your FX on another video.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to import you blender .png alpha enabled animation frames into after effects instead of using blender to render out a movie with an alpha channel that may not be supported elsewhere to begin with. Let's say you finally find a codec that supports alpha and then you want to stream that movie, most viewers might have to download that codec before they could watch your video. That is not user friendly.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) While these may be some valid points, the OP asked specifically about a video format (they even noted that they did not want to use png).