# Blender crashes when using video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to add a movie to Blender's video editor; a mpeg video. It crashes every time regardless of the size of the video. The video is an animation rendered out by Blender; .mpeg with mpeg2 codec.

While trying to solve it, I realized I need video with transparent background; so what format should I re-render out in that supports transparent background that I can then import into the video editor without crashing?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. [This question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2050/2217) answers your file format question.