# Can i animate my video in VSE after i have rendered all images with transparent background (black color)?

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, transparency

I believe i may have rendered all the frames incorrectly with the wrong setting. Basically i am trying to create a GIF of my my video with a transparent background. After i rendered the animation with the "transparent" box ticked in render properties, all the frames have just a black background. When i import these images into the GIF converter, it doesnt register the black background as alpha.

I believe i had to set the output as RGBA when i rendered the animation. Is there a way i can reprocess these images quickly without having to render the entire animation again?

Any help is much appreciated.

Alex

[image: Rendered frame with black background not alpha]

Comment: Render only the alpha pass into a separate image sequence, or render all objects in a pure white material with a black background, then add the alpha back to the original footage with the compositor to your existing renders

Comment: I think there is no solution that is any easier or quicker than just re-rendering. It looks like a straight forward scene.

Comment: read: [Any Video formats that render with Alpha Channel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/any-video-formats-that-render-with-alpha-channel)