# How to export PNG image sequence as GIF with transparency?

Tags: animation, export, video-sequence-editor, video

I’m trying to export an animated logo for my website.

I have the PNG image sequence with alpha channel ready to go. I can’t find a way to export or turn my image sequence into a GIF sequence (with transparency).

John

Comment: Not exactly, but perhaps some of the other software people mention there could be useful. I’ll check it out, thanks for the link. I’m specifically asking about transparency (GIF creation is secondary, although it looks like just exporting a GIF is already a problem).

Comment: Yes, I think GIF its' not supported. Video with transparency AFAIK can be made in Quicktime Format: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/any-video-formats-that-render-with-alpha-channel

Comment: I see. Well, the logo needs to be a transparent GIF, so I guess it’s time to go elsewhere for exporting this thing. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've already exported the animation into PNGs with transparent backgrounds, you can simply upload your images to a png to gif converter website such as [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/apng-to-gif) and download the result. Cheers!

Comment: This shouldn’t have been marked as a duplicate question. This is the answer right here, thank you stphnl329. It converts PNGs to APNGs, then APNGs to GIFs—perfect.