# Why does video rendered as .avi Raw appear with black background despite setting the 'transparent' render option?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I set transparent in the render properties, and output properties in .avi raw , but the animation I rendered came out as black background, why isn't it transparent?

Comment: The video format you chose does not support alpha channel. If your aim is to composite in other software use an image sequence in EXR.   read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/any-video-formats-that-render-with-alpha-channel

Comment: Same as cegaton said, getting alpha channels in video can be tricky unless you use the correct codecs(Apple prores or GoPro Cineform have alpha support). Exporting EXR or PNG stills would be the way to go. For what it's worth, I never render directly to video because if the render crashes you have to start from the beginning. If rendering to stills, you can start from the frame where the render crashed or where you stopped it.

Comment: can I use ffmpeg video in output? will that work?

Comment: It is preferable not to render directly as video, but as images first and then encode later. Ffmpeg is not a format, it is a toolkit to encode using different containers and codecs. Why do you need to encode with an alpha channel?