# How To Render PNG's With Transparent Background?

Tags: rendering

I have a series of PNG images that I've placed in the Video Sequencer.  I want to render them as an mp4 video, with a transparent background.

I've checked the Transparent box; selected FFmpeg video as the File Format; ticked the RGBA button; selected Quicktime as the Container; selected FFmpeg video codec #1; gone to Render Animation...and the resulting video cannot be opened with QuickTime Player ("file isn't compatible).

I then opened the same video in VLC, and the background is NOT TRANSPARENT.  I want to render the PNG images as an mp4, with a resulting transparent background.

I've tried many other Format/Container/Codec options as well, but cannot achieve a transparent background.  Hope this is concise enough that I might get some help? The file is here:[waving_flag](https://jumpshare.com/v/g2fWjWqg1d2VDD1VuBVM)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This thread should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2050/78972. Specifically this answer concerning Blender 2.8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/145475/78972

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once, see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thanks, Jachym.  I've looked at all of your links, and I'm prepared to say that I've tried every combination available, and none produce a transparent background.  There is either something wrong with my blend file (hyperlinked/attached to my initial inquiry above), or Blender 2.82 does not support transparency in video??

Comment: Duarte - I reposted because moderator brockmann told me to do so  He said my question was not clear and closed the original string.  I must say, I'm learning a lot about how and when to ask questions, and I only wish I could get resolution!

Comment: @jmarkt Hi. No, they asked you to *add* information to your question, not re-ask it. You should use the 'edit' link below your original question to add information.