# transparent video background not working

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to render video with transparent background, I do everything right I guess and after I render it and I'm trying to open with Windows Media Player, it says "We couldn't open .mov file" however when I open it with VLC it shows black background and green color when I upload video in blender video editor it also gets colors not how it was and background not even transparent.
How can I get video with transparent background and why my video colors have been changed?

[image: Transparent]
[image: color]

[image]

**Links to videos:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcec9xhrbyemjt5/2023-06-19%2022-42-19.mp4?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/003o91onh0fwtj4/2023-06-19%2022-50-06.mp4?dl=0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/any-video-formats-that-render-with-alpha-channel https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294813/export-a-video-in-transparent-for-use-on-the-web